# calling an object from a function in R - error object not found

Tags: r, object

I am trying to create a variable width column chart, each column representing the a non overlapping steps. the width would be the mean of the step and the height is the standard dev of each step. This was my original code:

```
df <- data.frame (Steps = c( "Step2", "Step3", "Step4", "Step5", "Step6", "Step7"), Variability = c(sd(dataset$PS02_days_creation_to_validation, na.rm = TRUE), sd(dataset$PS03_days_validation_to_sourcing, na.rm = TRUE), sd(dataset$PS04_days_sourcing_to_confirmation, na.rm = TRUE), sd(dataset$PS05_days_confirmation_to_ship_created, na.rm = TRUE),sd(dataset$PS06_days_ship_created_to_shipped, na.rm = TRUE), sd(dataset$PS07_days_shipped_to_reception,na.rm = TRUE) ), width = c(mean(dataset$PS02_days_creation_to_validation, na.rm = TRUE), mean(dataset$PS03_days_validation_to_sourcing, na.rm = TRUE), mean(dataset$PS04_days_sourcing_to_confirmation, na.rm = TRUE), mean(dataset$PS05_days_confirmation_to_ship_created,na.rm = TRUE), mean(dataset$PS06_days_ship_created_to_shipped,na.rm = TRUE), mean(dataset$PS07_days_shipped_to_reception,na.rm = TRUE) ))

df$w <- cumsum(df$width) #cumulative sums to gt the end points of each column.
df$wm <- df$w - df$width #giving the starting point of each column

library(ggplot2)
p  <- ggplot(df, aes(ymin = 0))
p1 <- p + geom_rect(aes(xmin = wm, xmax = w, ymax = Variability, fill = Steps))
p1
```

This code works fine when all the steps are positive. However when the width of the first step is negative, then my columns would overlap.
i.e.  4 steps with the following width =(25,50,75,100),   using the above code creates: end point w= (25,75,150,250) starting point wm= (0,25,75,150). Great!

Now if the the first step's width change to (-25,50,75,100) then the code produces w:(-25,25,100,200) and  wm:(0,-25,25,100)  which means that the steps are overlapping!!  Instead i would like to amend the code to produce: w=(-25,50,125,225) and wm:(0,0,50,125)

An R guru kindly suggested using this function:

```
widths_to_starts_ends <- function(widths){
  
  widths <- widths[widths != 0]
  pos_widths <- widths[widths > 0]
  neg_widths <- widths[widths < 0]
  
  pos_ends <- cumsum(pos_widths)
  pos_starts <- cumsum(pos_widths) - pos_widths
  
  neg_widths <- abs(neg_widths)
  neg_starts <- cumsum(neg_widths)
  neg_ends <- cumsum(neg_widths) - neg_widths
  
  neg_starts <- (-1)*neg_starts
  neg_ends <- (-1)*neg_ends
  
  return( list(s = c(neg_ends, pos_starts), e = c(neg_starts, pos_ends)) )
  
}

widths_to_starts_ends(c(-25,50,75,100))
```

which results in

```
$s 
[1] 0   0  50 125

$e
[1] -25  50 125 225
```

I would like to embed this function into my original code (to replace the w and wm lines with e and s) and make a graph but i am not sure how to call the objects E and S.  this is what im doing:

```
library(ggplot2)
p  <- ggplot(df, aes(ymin = 0))

p1 <- p + geom_rect(aes(xmin = s, xmax = e, ymax = Variability, fill = Steps))
p1
```

But it says object S is not found.  Could you help me please?

Comment: Where do you define `df`? All I see here is you calling `widths_to_starts_ends(.)` and not capturing its results, and then somehow `df` shows up.

Comment: You did not mention _df_ prior to that ggplot code, what does it contain?
FYI, ggplot expects a dataframe whose columns are named after the values of the parameters you provide in your aes.

Comment: Further, your function's return value is a `list`, but `ggplot` needs a `data.frame`. Third (and final for now), you are also trying to use `Variability` and `Steps` that have not been defined (as far as we know); based on the methods of ggplot2, I would expect those two variables to be within the `df` frame.

Comment: If the function is chanegd to return a data.frame instead of a list, and `df <- widths_to_starts_ends(.)`, then the `geom_rect` call gives an error: *"Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : object 'Variability' not found"*.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help.  I just rephrased my question.  Hope this time its more clear

Comment: What do you want to happen to your intervals if a 'negative width' is in the middle, say (-25, 50, -75, 100)?

Comment: @marcguery The -ve interval can only happen for the first step.  If so, I would like  the end points to be (-25,50,125,225) in other words, the first interval remains negative as is (starting at 0 ending at -25). and the other 3 steps would start from 0 instead of -25. so there would be no overlap of the steps.  I hope this helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand it correctly, you want to make a continuous series of intervals that are shifted by the first value of your list if it is negative.

Here is something more compact than what you have already to produce such intervals and store them in your dataframe:

```
df$e <- cumsum(abs(df$width)) + min(0, df$width[1])
df$s <- c(min(0, df$width[1]), df$e[-length(df$e)])
df$s #starting points
#[1] -25   0  50 125
df$e #ending points
#[1]   0  50 125 225
```

Then, the corresponding plot would be obtained with:

```
p  <- ggplot(df, aes(ymin = 0))
p1 <- p + geom_rect(aes(xmin = s, xmax = e, ymax = Variability, fill = Steps))
p1
```

[image]

Data that I used:

```
set.seed(123456789)
df <- data.frame (Steps = c( "Step2", 
                             "Step3", 
                             "Step4", 
                             "Step5"), 
                  Variability = c(sd(1:500/sample(1:10, 1)), 
                                  sd(1:500/sample(1:10, 1)), 
                                  sd(1:500/sample(1:10, 1)), 
                                  sd(1:500/sample(1:10, 1))), 
                  width = c(-25,50,75,100))
```

Comment: Incredible!!!!  Thank you so much Marcguery.  This is exactly what i was trying to achieve but i couldn't even formulate my question clearly.  Thanks a Million and have a lovely day

Answer (score 1):

s and e appear to be elements of a list, not standalone objects, which I imagine is why they can’t be found. In your function you could instead return a dataframe *df* containing s and e columns and then make your ggplot call

```
ggplot(df, aes(xmin = s, xmax = e...)) + geom_rect()
```